# C# Strange Behavior

Tags: c#, class, constructor, struct, initialization

I have a custom struct :

```
struct A
{
    public int y;
}
```

a custom class with empty constuctor:

```
class B
{
    public A a;
    public B()
    {
    }
}
```

and here is the main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    B b = new B();
    b.a.y = 5;//No runtime errors!
    Console.WriteLine(b.a.y);
}
```

When I run the above program, it does not give me any errors, although I did not initialize struct A in class B constructor..'a=new A();'

Comment: I am confused by the question. Why would you expect a *runtime* error? I can see why you would expect a *compile-time* error, but why would you expect a *runtime* error? I suspect that your belief that a runtime error is appropriate here is symptomatic of a deep misunderstanding of what "value type" means. Can you explain why you think that this should be a runtime, not a compile time error?  Would you likewise expect a runtime error if the type of field "a" was "double" instead of struct A? Why or why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I did not initialize struct A in class B constructor.

C# does this for you. All members of classes are initialized to their default values unless you assign them other values in their declaration or the constructor.

For `class` instances, the default value is `null` and you’d get an error when using that instance. However, for `struct` instances (which are *not* references unlike class instances), there doesn’t exist a `null` value. The default value of a `struct` is an instance where all its fields have been default-initialized.

That’s why your code works.